# How to use Swift Package Manager in Xcode 9 Playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground, swift-package-manager

Is it possible to use Swift Package Manager inside Xcode 9 Playground?

Comment: I think there is a good material that can help you. 
1) https://swift.org/package-manager/#conceptual-overview  
2) https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2016-02-25-14-00-3_steps_to_marry_xcode_with_swift_package_manager/
3) https://www.raywenderlich.com/148832/introduction-swift-package-manager
4) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIWqkg9Ry1g

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to use the Swift Package Manager in a playground at this time. The reason for that is that the Swift Package Manager is primarily used outside of apple platforms.

[Apple](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/) mentions this on the Swift Package Manager's GitHub:

> Note that at this time the Package Manager has no support for iOS, watchOS, or tvOS platforms

The Swift Package Manager is especially useful for writing Swift for platforms such as Linux and Mac. Uses may include creating servers based written in Swift or writing programs that can be run without a user interface (think home automations and IoT). It is a great way to organize packages without using Pods or other third-party setups. When you build the code for production (or debugging) it will download and incorporate packages into the project.

Note: This may change in the future, but is current as of Swift 3

Comment: Your answer has been deprecated. What about now?

Comment: This answer is now out of date (as it noted it may become). I'm voting down for now to try to make the more recent answer more visible but would reverse that if it was updated with the latest information.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 12, you can use Swift Packages with Xcode Playgrounds.

Steps to setup a workspace with a Swift Package and a Playground:

- Open Xcode
- Create a new Workspace (`File > New > Workspace...`)
- Add the desired Swift package via `File > Add Files to "Workspace Name"...` selecting the package directory.
- Create a new Playground via `File > New > Playground...`. Ensure that you select the Workspace we just created as the "Add to" and "Group" option during Playground creation (in the assistant where you select the Playground's location on disk).
- You can now import the Package target into your Playground and starting exploring the Package's functionality.

You can find additional details and a sample project in this WWDC20 session: [Explore Packages and Projects with Xcode Playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10096)

Ensure to check the new "Build active scheme" checkbox in the inspector for your existing Playgrounds.

Comment: But you still have to download the package manually and can't just import a package from a remote server

Comment: I followed those instructions but when I add the import statement, wit the module name copied and pasted from Package.swift, I get the "No such module" error. This is using Xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300).

Comment: Probably worth filing a bug report with Apple. You can check if the package actually built successfully in the build log you can find in Xcode’s Report navigator.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 12, playgrounds can work seamlessly with swift packages in a project.

Please follow the steps below:

1. Create a project named `Playground`:

   File → New → Project... (⇧⌘N) → Product Name: Playground

   ⚠️ You can name it whatever you want, here is just an example.
2. Add a swift package for the project, such as `SnapKit`:

   File → Swift Packages → Add Package dependency... → https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit.git
3. Create a playground and add it to the project created in the first step:

   File → New → Playground... (⌥⇧⌘N) → Add to: `Playground`
4. Import the swift package (SnapKit) in the Playground:

   ```
   import SnapKit
   ```

If nothing else, you can use `SnapKit` in the Playground.

Comment: Thank you for this info. I wonder if it will be ever possible to use a Package Manager without creating a project.