# How to import Swift Package in Playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground, swift-package-manager

Can i import Swift Package to my Playground that is in my workspace? I've already read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42736864/2463616), but i think it's outdated, because now we can use Swift Packages in iOS projects.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Xcode 12, you can use Swift Packages with Xcode Playgrounds.

- Open Xcode
- Create a new Workspace (`File > New > Workspace...`)
- Add the desired Swift package via `File > Add Files to "Workspace Name"...` selecting the package directory.
- Create a new Playground via `File > New > Playground...`. Ensure that you select the Workspace we just created as the "Add to" and "Group" option during Playground creation (in the assistant where you select the Playground's location on disk).
- You can now import the Package target into your Playground and starting exploring the Package's functionality.

You can find additional details and a sample project in this WWDC20 session: [Explore Packages and Projects with Xcode Playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10096)

Ensure to check the new "Build active scheme" checkbox in the inspector for your **existing** Playgrounds.

Comment: Step-by-step, how does one "import the Package target into your Playground"?

Comment: Add `import MyPackage` at the top of your Playground code (replace `MyPackage` with your package name)

Comment: As of XCode14.2 at least, you need a project inside the workspace and have to add the playground to the project, to be able to add packages. See alex1704's answer for details. The workspace is actually irrelevant, it's the project that counts.

Comment: This does not work in Xcode 15.

Answer (score 15):

Check out [Arena](https://github.com/finestructure/Arena), it allows you to create playgrounds with SPM dependencies embedded ready for use.

All it takes is

```
brew install finestructure/tap/arena
arena alamofire/alamofire
```

Update: The [Swift Package Index](https://swiftpackageindex.com) has since gained [Arena integration](https://blog.swiftpackageindex.com/posts/launching-the-swift-package-index-playgrounds-app-for-macos) and you can create a playground for a package by clicking the "Try in a Playground" button on a package page.

Answer (score 6):

Still now, Playground does not support the Swift Package Manager.
When we try to add the Swift PM from Xcode using

```
File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency
```

the option is disabled.

[image]

An option is to use [nef](https://github.com/bow-swift/nef) - it is an open-source project an lets you import third-party libraries in your Playgrounds. For now, it is compatible with Cocoapods but nef are working on open it for other dependency managers like Carthage and SPM.

About SPM is not an easy task, and it will be a bit different as Apple has prepared Xcode11 but I have good feelings and I think it could be ready for Sept-Oct.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get @wolfrevo's answer working. However, I have a solution inspired by his:

1. Open Xcode
2. Create a **New Project** (`File > New > Project`)
3. Choose `Muliplatform > App` > **Next**
4. Project Name: *Whatever* > **Next**
5. **Create**
6. Now add the dependency (`File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency`)
7. Paste package git url: https://github.com/maxhumber/Carlo.git > **Next**
8. Select rules, or skip > **Next**
9. **Finish**
10. Create a new Playground file in this project by short-cutting *Cmd+N*
11. Search `Playground` > **Next**
12. **Create**

Comment: I got "Symbol Not Found" errors for the package that i added until i restarted xcode (12.2) ...lol

Answer (score 2):

XCode 14.2

1. Create new project (ex. iOS app)
2. File > New > Playground
3. File > Add Packages (choose your package)
4. Reload XCode
5. `import Package` in Playground

If XCode still do not see package then:
File > Packages > Resolve Package Versions

Comment: I don't get Add Packages enabled in iOS or macOS (blank) playgrounds in XCode14.2. Is there another step or something more specific?

Comment: @AndyDent you need to create new project not new playground (see point 1).

Comment: Ahh, the gotcha was I failed to add the new Playground to the Project, in the New Playground 2nd screen, from File - New Playground. (Yes I know that's probably obvious but pretty sure that's what I got wrong). Thanks!

Comment: Same steps as wolfrevo albeit project instead of workspace?