Cant add package dependencies to xcode playground
I wanted to add a package to my XCode playground but its greyed out:

How to find out why I cant anything?

Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63121021/437242
First need to create a workspace, then the playground in it and then it can be selected
